# How do I get rid of tar spots appearing on my maple's leaves?

Tags: tree-care, diseases, maple

Preliminary reading suggests that the only way is to rake up the fallen leaves and get rid of them.  Will this do the trick?

Is there a way I could keep the leaves for compost without propagating the tar spot fungus to next year?

Comment: You don't say where you are in your profile.  I'm in southern New Hampshire, and it became ubiquitous here over the last 5 or so years.  Getting rid of the leaves doesn't seem to help any - for me.  It's really ugly.

Comment: @EdStaub, Have you tried a fungicide to get rid of the tar spots?  Thanks.

Comment: No - we have 3 25-foot trees and 3 50-foot trees, and we're in the city with lots of surrounding trees, some infected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This [site](http://www.uoguelph.ca/pdc/Factsheets/Diseases/TarspotMaple.htm) describes the tar spot. It does not harm the tree but is unsightly.  The causal agent, a fungus, overwinters on the leaves.  If your neighbours have maple trees and don't follow rigorous cleanup chances are good cleanup work on your part will not reduce the chance of infection.

> ["Short-term composting of mulches in windrows under high-temperature conditions (130-160 degrees F) kills these plant pathogens. Six weeks of composting is sufficient to kill most plant pathogens and avoid their dissemination in mulches or composts."](http://ohioline.osu.edu/hyg-fact/3000/3304.html)

That being said it's hard to provide uniform temperature for an extended period of time with a homeowner composting set up. 
I wouldn't take the chance that your compost will provide the right temperatures.